# Is there a way to use sample rate with the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We are thinking of implementing the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol to track older devices that may not have js enabled. Is there a way to set a sample rate when working with this protocol?

I have read through [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/limits-quotas) but not sure how you would go about introducing sample rates using the G.A.M.P. or even how to implement your own sample rate.

Comment: I am just curious why would you want to set a sample rate?

Comment: The website visitor numbers would exceed the Google Quotas

Comment: Measurement protocol lets you insert 1 million Hits into a Google Analytics web property each day.  If you insert more then it will just stop recording the data that day.  There wont be any error.  Google may contact you and ask you if you are interested in pay for a professional account but I don't think they are going to force one on you.   If you really have that much data then your going to have to implement some kind of sample rate yourself.  Either way I wonder how accurate your data will be in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sample rate is a feature implemented by the other client libraries (e.g. analytics.js and the iOS/Android SDKs), and they do it by selectively not sending hits for certain users to the Measurement Protocol.

If you wanted to implement this yourself, you could do the same. The key gotcha to keep in mind is you wouldn't want to randomly sample out individual hits, you'd want to randomly sample out users. To understand why the former is bad, consider if you didn't send a transaction event for a particular user, but then you did send a refund event. Your reports wouldn't make sense.